# Bootstrap display flex and javascript windows.load

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm no expert at front end dev. I'm experiencing an issue with bootstrap display flex and a piece of javascript code. Below is a bootstrap snippet with display: flex and some javascript that does some transitions. When the display: flex is present the javascript prevents the thumbnails boxes from being displayed. I would like to have both the display: flex and the javascript in use so that my transitions work and the flex boxes are all equal height. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div id="portfolio">
<div class="container">
<div class="section-title text-center center">
<h2>Some Header</h2>
</div>
<div class="categories">
  <ul class="cat">
    <li>
      <ol class="type">
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".web">Web Apps</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".app">Blogs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".branding">Code</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="display: flex">
<div class="portfolio-items">
    <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3 web">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Some Heading</h4>
                <p>Some Content</p>
                <div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Go to App</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3 web">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Some Heading</h4>
                <p>Some Content</p>
                <div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Go to App</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 $(window).load(function() {
    var $container = $('.portfolio-items');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
    });
    $('.cat a').click(function() {
        $('.cat .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: What did you want to do with that button using your script?

Comment: It transitions the thumbnail boxes around. Which works fine until I add display: flex

Comment: I am sorry, Can't understand, If I tried your script it shows error

Comment: Thanks for help. I've updated the code to show where the category transitions appear in the html

Comment: If you use Bootstrap V4, then the `.row` class will have `display:flex` property. With `.row` class you can add`.align-items-stretch`. It will make all the items same height. You better remove the `.portfolio-items` div, because `column` should be direct child of `row`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add display property for thumbnail class, if i get the question, this should help:

https://codepen.io/dichado/pen/yLyqYLZ

```
<div class="row" style="display: flex;">
<div class="portfolio-items">
    <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3 web">
        <div class="thumbnail" style="display: inline-flex;">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Some Heading</h4>
                <p>Some Content</p>
                <div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Go to App</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3 web">
        <div class="thumbnail" style="display: inline-flex;">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>Some Heading</h4>
                <p>Some Content</p>
                <div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Go to App</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```